# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_LINE' . Getting This error when passing a string argument in my function in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

This is my function which takes parameter of type department.dept_name%type. Which is varchar2(20)

````
```
create or replace function count_doc(dep_name_local department.dept_name%TYPE)
return number is
x int;
begin
select count(doc_id) into x from doctor where dept_no in(select dept_no  from department where dept_name=dep_name_local); 
return x;
end;

 ```
````

This is my function call.

````
    declare
    dep_namePass department.dept_name%TYPE;
    
    begin
    dep_namePass:='Cardiology';
    dbms_output.get_line(count_doc(dep_namePass));
    end;

     ```
Please tell me what am I doing wrong. I am a beginner :( . I am doing this in livesql btw.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `dbms_output.put_line`, not `get_line`.